# Libyaml missing after installing RVM ruby-1.9.3-p125 32-bit on OSX Lion

Tags: ruby, osx-lion, rvm

The rvm installation went fine for 32 bit.  The output even makes it look like yaml was installed fine

```
Kyles-MacBook-Air:~ kpeyton$ export rvm_archflags='-arch i386'
Kyles-MacBook-Air:~ kpeyton$ export rvm_architectures='i386'
Kyles-MacBook-Air:~ kpeyton$ export rvm_configure_flags=--target=i686-apple-darwin11
Kyles-MacBook-Air:~ kpeyton$ rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p125 --32 --patch osx-arch-fix -n i386
Fetching yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /Users/kpeyton/.rvm/archives
Extracting yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /Users/kpeyton/.rvm/src
Configuring yaml in /Users/kpeyton/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
Compiling yaml in /Users/kpeyton/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
Installing yaml to /Users/kpeyton/.rvm/usr
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/kpeyton/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125-i386, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...

ruby-1.9.3-p125-i386 - #fetching 
ruby-1.9.3-p125-i386 - #extracting ruby-1.9.3-p125 to /Users/kpeyton/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p125-i386
ruby-1.9.3-p125-i386 - #extracted to /Users/kpeyton/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p125-i386
Applying patch 'osx-arch-fix' (located at /Users/kpeyton/.rvm/patches/ruby/1.9.3/p125/osx-arch-fix.patch)
Applying patch 'xcode-debugopt-fix-r34840' (located at /Users/kpeyton/.rvm/patches/ruby/1.9.3/p125/xcode-debugopt-fix-r34840.diff)
ruby-1.9.3-p125-i386 - #autoreconf
ruby-1.9.3-p125-i386 - #configuring 
ruby-1.9.3-p125-i386 - #compiling 
ruby-1.9.3-p125-i386 - #installing 
Removing old Rubygems files...
Installing rubygems-1.8.24 for ruby-1.9.3-p125-i386 ...
Installation of rubygems completed successfully.
ruby-1.9.3-p125-i386 - adjusting #shebangs for (gem irb erb ri rdoc testrb rake).
ruby-1.9.3-p125-i386 - #importing default gemsets (/Users/kpeyton/.rvm/gemsets/)
Install of ruby-1.9.3-p125-i386 - #complete
```

But when I try to use irb and require 'yaml' I get an error about libyaml not being installed:

```
Kyles-MacBook-Air:~ kpeyton$ rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p125-i386
Using /Users/kpeyton/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125-i386
Kyles-MacBook-Air:~ kpeyton$ irb
1.9.3p125 :001 > require 'yaml'
/Users/kpeyton/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125-i386/lib/ruby/1.9.1/yaml.rb:56:in `<top (required)>':
It seems your ruby installation is missing psych (for YAML output).
To eliminate this warning, please install libyaml and reinstall your ruby.
 => true
```

Can anyone tell me what I should do?

Comment: why not use 64bit ruby/libyaml: `rm -rf $rvm_path/usr; rvm reinstall 1.9.3 --64`

Comment: I have to use Oracle because of work and the oracle instantclient does not work on 64 bit Lion OSX.

Comment: have a look on this https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/blob/master/scripts/functions/build#L66-L80 ... it's the code RVM was using earlier for ruby 1.8 ... but ruby 1.9 introduced easier switches for architectures, but they are not working for libyaml - maybe something new should be added for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-arch=i386" CFLAGS="-arch i386" LDFLAGS="-arch i386" rvm pkg install libyaml
```

to compile libyaml in 32-bit and then reinstall your ruby version:

```
rvm reinstall ruby-1.9.3-p125-i386 -n i386 --with-arch=i386
```

Comment: Your answer seems to have fixed the fact that it wasn't working.  However, I'm still seeing the same warning message from before.  So a partial solution, but thanks anyway!